# iOS 13 Core NFC Error to detecting any Tags

Tags: swift, nfc, ios13, xcode11, core-nfc

I have an Error with iOS 13 CoreNFC to detect any Tag. I Downloaded the sample Project from apple and add all the additional Data to my Projekt (info plist and the utilities). I also created the Apple ID and the provisioning Profile with the same name as the bundle ID. The `session.begin` and `tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive` works fine without any Error. Xcode print out the the following error, while bringing my iPhone near to the NFC SMART CARD READER(ACR122u on Raspberry pi).

```
<NSXPCConnection: 0x2817b42d0> connection to service on pid 88 named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc: Exception caught during decoding of received selector didDetectExternalReaderWithNotification:, dropping incoming message.
Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
Exception: decodeObjectForKey: class "NFFieldNotification" not loaded or does not exist
```

I read about the Error, that maybe the provision profile is the reason, but this works fine

What should I do ? I didn't find any solution about this Error?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I was working on this and found a solution which worked for me, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65613850/4820276)'s my answer to a similar question